# How is this possible in Java? (in an Android program)

Tags: java, android

In an Android program I was noticing that the value of a variable seemed to be changing unexpectedly.   This is happening in a singleInstance Activity in my app.  I must be overlooking something obvious but I've had a co-worker who knows java look at it and she doesn't see anything either . . .

I have a really simple  class, SignalItem...

```
public class SignalItem {

    public int signal;
    public int position;

    public SignalItem () {
        signal = 0;
        position = 0;
    }
}
```

Here's my routine that uses it (it used to do more stuff) . . .

```
 public static void add2Q(int signal, int position) {
    SignalItem sigI = new SignalItem();
    sigI.signal = signal;      // signal=0.   Step from here to ...
    sigI.position = position;  // ...here sigI.signal changes from 0 to 28! 
}
```

In the debugger the input arguments signal and position are 0.   When I instantiate sigI, its members are also 0, as they should be because that's how the constructor inits them.  But when I step from the assignment of signal to the assignment of position **sigI.signal gets set to 28**.  How/Why?  The input argument signal remains 0.

SignalItem is not static -  I can make multiple instances of it (sigI2, sigI3, etc) and they remain unaffected.  Add2Q is not re-entered - a breakpoint set on the first line does not get hit again.    All of this is happening in the same thread (Thread[<1> main)  Since sigI is instantiated locally how can it change?

It's not an artifact of the debugger -  if I write these to logcat they all reflect what I'm seeing in the debugger.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: That seems awfully strange. So you are 100% sure that both your arguments you pass into add20 is zero? aka yourclass.add2Q(0,0);

I would also add a logger to log your values that you recieve.

Comment: Unrelated, but `extends Object` is superfluous.

Comment: If you move one level down the call stack in the debugger, what value is assigned to the variable passed as the first argument?

Comment: `extends Object` is redundant (Unless it's not `java.lang`..).

Comment: This can only happen if the running code is out-of-date.

Comment: Yes, I wrote them all out to logcat - several times in the code to see any changes.  I just didn't include them in the above to avoid clutter.

Comment: You appear to have shortened your code for us (thank you). However, did you try running the actual code you gave us to see if it still causes the problem?

Comment: @ Dave Newton  - as I said in my OP, add2Q used to do other stuff.  What it used to do is add sigI to a collection class, so it needed to be Object.

Comment: @ Daniel Renshaw   it's called with (0,0)

Comment: @user316117 *Every* class in Java extends object. Doing it explicitly is superfluous.

Comment: @supersam654   Yes, the code you see is the code with the weird behavior.

Comment: @user316117 can you provide us with more information/code?

Comment: @user316117 another thing to think about is that primitive ints defaults to zero. your constructor doesn't really do anything

Comment: @Dave Newton   I didn't know that.  I took out the extends object - no change.

Comment: @user316117 That's why I said "unrelated" :)

Comment: We need more information. Something else is going on because there is nothing wrong with the code you provided (at least, nothing that would cause `signal` to become `28`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the information given, nothing can modify that instance of SignalItem.

Things to check:

- Are you running the code you think you are?
- Are you certain it's the same instance?
- Have you checked the stack in the debugger to see where another call might be coming from?

Answer (score 1):

When your debugger is on the line

```
sigI.signal = signal
```

and it shows sigI.signal == 0, that's because it hasn't executed that line yet.  When it goes to the next line, it will have executed that previous line and sigI.signal will be equal to the input value signal.  I think you just have some debugger confusion or something.

Comment: I agree there's confusion or mis-deployment, but the OP states it's being called with 0, 0.

Comment: There's no debugger confusion, as I said in another response, if I put a logcat at every line it outputs exactly what the debugger shows, i.e., signal stays 0, sigI.signal changes from 0 to 28.

Comment: @user316117 If they're the same SignalItem instance (which I assume you've verified) then there *is* some confusion somewhere: you're either not running the code you think you are, or there's a system interaction you're not aware of.

Comment: Good call!  They're NOT the same instance!   It didn't occur to me to check that because I couldn't imagine that could happen.  This is a singleInstance Activity and all in the same thread.    How can this happen?

Comment: @user316117 There isn't a single instance or there's another thread? Without any other context that's an impossible question to answer.

Comment: "singleInstance" is an Android launch mode but maybe there's some fine print I need to understand.   Anyway if you'd like to post your4 suggestion about checking if it's the same instance, I can mark that as "the answer" and close this thread -  it clearly explains the mystery.

Answer (score 1):

It might make more sense to define your object like so:

```
public class SignalItem extends Object {

    public int signal;
    public int position;

    public SignalItem (int signal, int position) {
        this.signal = signal;
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

Then you can call your constructor like so:

```
public static void add2Q(int signal, int position) {
    SignalItem sigI = new SignalItem(signal, position);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that "Object" that you are extending is the java.lang.Object (which make the code redundant), if not that might be where your problem is.

Try make your member variable private and set them using setter or constructor.

Comment: it is OK to extend the object class, that is just redundancy when he does that. It is also OK to make it a public variable to access directly rather than using getter and setter. What we don't know is HOW the values are set.

Answer (score 0):

Go back and take a look at Dave Newtons answer - that you probably aren't debugging the code that is running.

This can happen quite easily - if there is another version of either the .java file or the .class file of the same name, get rid of them and try everything again.  This can and does happen, even if the file is in a directory the project knows nothing about, and even if the file is in a jar or zip.